# Image for the File Menu of JMenuBar

Tags: java, jmenubar

I have created a complete menu bar for my java program and it is all functioning correctly, however I would like to have an image for the file menu, instead of text. I know you can add and icon or image for JMenuItem's but is it possible to do it for the JMenu itself.

So instead of text where it says "File" or "Edit" have images there so that when you click the image it displays the drop down/JMenuItem's?

A short snippet from my code is below

```
    //File Menu.
    JLabel fileButton = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("buttonfile.jpg"));
    MenuBarFile = new JMenu("file");
    //MenuBarFile.setIcon("buttonfile.jpg");
    menuBar.add(menu);
```

The class extends JMenuBar by the way, and is added into another class where needed.

By the way I have tried the obvious which is:

```
menuBar.add(fileButton);
```

Adding a JLabel image to the menuBar doesn't do anything, it just displays blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) inherits from AbstractButton, which has a [setIcon() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) allowing to set the icon of the menu.

BTW, JMenu also inherits from JMenuItem. So if you managed to set an icon on a JMenuItem, you should be able to do it, the same way, on a JMenu.

Comment: menu = new JMenu("File", new ImageIcon("buttonfile.jpg"));
That is how I set it for the JMenuItem but when I do the same for the JMenu it gives a cannot find symbol error

Comment: Read the javadoc. I even gave you the link to it. JMenu doesn't have such a constructor. But it still has a `setIcon()` method. The designers of the class probably didn't provide such a constructor because a JMenu with an icon is almost never wanted.

Comment: Done, my syntax was wrong, thanks for the help, it just that I am creating a Microsoft Office look for my program, I wanted an image and not text there thats why.